# iOS Image Asset sizing. Is 3x actually 3 times the 1x size and is Retina 4 2x required?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcasset

I'm trying to wrap my head around everything and to make sure I do everything properly.

I've been looking at [The Ultimate Guide to iPhone Resolutions](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) and want clarification on 3x and Retina 4 2x.

For 3x, apparently the images get downsampled. I shouldn't care about that, right? All I need to do is put an image whose width and whose height is 3 times greater than that of the 1x image. Of course, with the intent that I'm scaling the image. So it follows the same exact step from 1x to 2x in that I just make the size larger. Is that correct?

Then, I see the iPhone 5 and iPhone 5s which I think both use Retina 4 2x. Is Retina 4 2x required? If not, it just defaults to 2x, right? What differences should there be between the Retina 4 2x and the 2x image? How would I scale the width and height differently?

Comment: It's not worth a whole answer for this, so: for 3x, on the currently released device, technically the whole output screen will be downsampled. The individual assets won't be — an actual full-screen @3x screen buffer is composed and then that is scaled. Which makes a difference re:subpixel accuracy. But, no, don't worry about it. It's dealt with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting a little confused. There is just the normal, @2x and @3x. There is no "retina 2x".

`imageName.png 60 x 60
imageName@2x.png 120 x 120
imageName@3x.png 180 x 180`

Your code will be: image = `[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];` and iOS will do the rest for you. Same goes if you're using interface builder. Just put in the standard image.

Comment: For splash screens, that is all.

Comment: For example, your iPhone portrait would be 320 x 480, the 4 inch would be 320 x 586, the retina 4 would be 640 x 1136.

Comment: Check the Apple HIG for sizes: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Comment: I'd rather not make another question on StackOverflow, Gary, so I thought I could just ask here: I'm reading https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppIcons.html and it says it iOS automatically masks the App Icon on the home screen, but the Spotlight, Settings, etc. App Icons are all under the same Image Set in Xcode so I was wondering if it applies the mask to every App Icon on iOS

Comment: Yep. If you don't upload those then iOS will use the larger icon, masked correctly. You can get photoshop templates that will crest all the icons do you if you did want to supply them. iOS always applies the mask, so always use square icons.

Comment: Retina 4 2x does not exists anymore